# How to register two service worker for two different scopes in the same domain

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

In my PWA I got two service-worker: one for '/' (root) scope, registered by my code

```
const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js', {
        scope: '/',
      });
```

where I want to manage the fetch events with some cache, and one for 'firecloud-messaging-push-scope', registered by firebase library and used to manage push notification with firebase code.

For some reason I cannot register the root service-worker as chrome flag it as redundant. This piss me off cause I cannot intercept fetch event from the firebase scoped service-worker.

How can I overcome this?

[image]

[image]

I expect to register one sw for root scope and many other for ant nested path of the pwa.

**UPDATE**
I excluded the firebase service-worker and I found out that root serice worker still is redundant-deleted, but I get no error from its installation/activation.